# Email to Salesforce that sends a Queue Notification

Tags: email, notification

I was wondering if there is a way to send an email to a salesforce email address that would then notify a queue with the contents of the original email.  I'm trying to make this as simple as possible.  I'm thinking that I'll have to use email to case, but I'm trying to get around that.

This situation is an external problem effects a large group of accounts, and we want to let Customer Support know that there is a problem and what accounts are effected.  Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce offers inbound email service. Basically you can generate a salesforce email. Whenever email is sent to that address, you can execute apex class and process the content of email. Checkout the link - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com

Comment: I will see if that is what is needed.  I believe they may just want a splash screen now.  But yes I imagine i could use the email services and process the email as you pointed out.  Thanks.